# How to send variables from index.php to ajaximage.php in ajax image uploading?

Tags: jquery, image, file-upload

I need to send users logid and input id to server along with image uploaded with jquery. Only thing i get to send is image.  Here is my current code:
index.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$session_id='1'; //$session id
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('.photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
            var id=$(this).attr("id");
                var split=id.split("photoimg");
var splited=split[1];
                alert(splited); 

                   $("#preview").html('');
                $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview'
        }).submit();

            });
        }); 
</script>


<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'><br>
Upload your image1 <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg1" class="photoimg"/><br>
Upload your image2 <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg2" class="photoimg"/><br>
Upload your image3 <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg3" class="photoimg"/><br>
</form>
<div id='preview'>
</div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add the parameters to the action of the form as follows:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php?logid=XXX'>
```

or if the var is PHP which is likely:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php?logid=<?php echo $logId;?>'>
```

and then process it in ajaximage.php with:

```
$_GET['logid']
```

Comment: No problem :). Can you accept my answer then please? It's the green tick under the number 0 up and left :)